# Separar dados string de uma tabela em outras tabelas

Tags: mysql, sql, string, table, tabela-html

Bom dia,
Possuo uma tabela chamada TP_SAN_SRV, que é a tabela que possui o tipo e o fator sanguíneo, porém preciso separar elas em duas, onde o tipo e o fator sanguíneo fiquem separados.

Procurei por aqui e vi que da pra usar o string split, porém não consegui utilizar para separar palavras juntas e sim em quando vem com uma ou mais palavras.

Alguém tem alguma ideia do que poderei utilizar?

Utilizo o mysql server.

Obrigado.

Comment: Se você diz que utiliza o MySQL Server por que marcou a tag "oracle"?

Comment: Foi uma falta de atenção apenas. Obg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opa, passei algo parecido a pouco tempo e não achei nenhum conteúdo que me ajudasse, tive que pedir ajuda a um amigo. Acho que da pra resolver teu problema com isso:

```
SELECT SUBSTR (tp_san_srv,1,1) as TIPO_SANGUE, SUBSTR (tp_san_srv,2,1) as Tp_SANGUE_FATOR FROM SRH2.servidor;
```

Ai é só adaptar pro nome das tuas colunas

Comment: Obg. Funcionou aqui adaptando ao meu schema.